# Is it possible to craft a certificate signing chain that thwarts MITM corporate VPNs?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, vpn

Some companies install software on corporate VPNs which also come with a root certificate installed on all employees' machines. This allows for encrypted traffic to be decrypted by technology installed on the VPN. Some companies even *have* to do this to meet certain auditing and compliance requirements.

Is it possible for a website to set up a certificate signing chain in a way that if the root cert that signed it was replaced by the MITM root cert, it would either fail to load the website, or prevent it from being overwritten by the root cert entirely in the first place?

Or, if there's a root cert installed on a machine, is it impossible to prevent TLS intercepting by a MITM party?

Comment: What has this to do with VPN? Aren't you basically asking if a web server certificate can be setup in a way that the traffic cannot be transparently intercepted and decrypted by corporate MITM solution where a new root CA is installed as trusted at the client?

Comment: I'm making the distinction that the MITM software is running on a network, not locally on a machine

Comment: A corporate proxy is running on the network. When using a VPN the interception is also done (in the corporate proxy) on the network, not on the local machine. Interception on the local machine is for example done by several Desktop Antivirus products. Still - the basic idea is always the same and the answer is independent of VPN or not, network or local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding you are essentially asking if a web server certificate can be setup in a way that the traffic cannot be transparently intercepted and decrypted by corporate MITM solution, which a new root CA is installed as trusted at the client. I.e. the question is not specific to VPN.

In a MITM setup the MITM proxy is basically the client to the original server and thus gets the servers certificate and chain. It then works as a server to the original client but sends a different certificate and chain. Since the client has no idea how the original certificate and chain looked like but trusts the CA for the new certificate, the client will trust the new certificate too. This means that **simply with some magic on the certificate and chain it is not possible to protect against MITM**.

Protection can instead be done if the client has more expectations to the server certificate than just being signed by a trusted CA. Such expectations can be achieved if the clients limits which certificates it accepts by certificate, the certificates public key or the certificates issuer (CA). Such **pinning** is implemented for  some commonly attacked domains in many browsers. But in order to facility legal SSL interception done in corporate proxies but also desktop Antivirus products, pinning is usually automatically switched off when the served certificate was issued by a root CA which was explicitly imported as trusted.

Another protection would be if the server has more expectations to the client. By **requiring a client certificate** issued by a specific CA the server can also make sure that the traffic cannot be successfully intercepted. Instead the TLS connection will usually just fail, unless there is an explicit exception for the target site in the MITM proxy. Of course, the client must actually have the client certificate installed in the first place to connect to the server without MITM which somehow limits this approach.

The target server could also try to **detect interception by fingerprinting the TLS stack of the client** and then block access if interception is detected - see [Detect man-in-the-middle on server side for HTTPS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110599/detect-man-in-the-middle-on-server-side-for-https) for more on this. Note that this detection is not perfect, i.e. can have false positives and false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

> Some companies install corporate VPNs which also come with a root certificate installed on all employees' machines. This allows for encrypted traffic to be decrypted by technology installed on the VPN. Some companies even have to do this to meet certain auditing and compliance requirements.

This does not make a lot of sense. Companies install corporate VPNs that terminate in their own equipment, there is no need to decrypt the traffic, as they can observe it on the server as it comes out of the VPN server.

> Is it possible for a website to set up a certificate signing chain in a way that if root cert that signed it is replaced by the corporate VPNs root cert,
>   it would either fail to load the website, or prevent it from being overwritten by the root cert entirely in the first place?

This isn't something you can do from a web server. TLS inspection occurs by influencing how the client handles server side certificates.

You are also mixing the concepts of a corporate VPN and TLS inspection.

A VPN is simply a method of establishing a virtual network connection to an endpoint located in a particular network. It involves authentication and encryption of traffic exchanged with the server. Nothing stops you from using encrypted protocols within your VPN connection.

TLS inspection is a technique used on a given network whereby a piece of software intercepts client initiated TLS connections and acts as the server using a certificate that has been signed by an internal CA certificate (not the actual root level CA that signs the certificate chain of the server you are trying to reach). This is done to terminate the encrypted connection at the local network, observe the traffic in plain text, and re-encrypt it into a connection to the actual destination server. It's essentially transparent TLS man in the middle.